# Zsh CASE_SENSITIVE does nothing

Tags: zsh, case-sensitive, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I installed my Mac with a case sensitive filesystem.

Everything is fine, other than Zsh not being as fluent as it used to be. I've confirmed the Oh-My-Zsh variable `CASE_SENSITIVE` is commented out in *.zshrc* but it's still failing to find folders of different cases when using tab autocompletion.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ mkdir foo fOo FOO
$ cd f<tab>
foo/ fOo/
```

I've confirmed `CASE_SENSITIVE` is unset:

```
$ [[ -z "$CASE_SENSITIVE" ]] && echo Yep
Yep
```

Is this a bug, or am I just missing something?

Comment: What is `CASE_SENSITIVE`? That's not a standard `zsh` environment variable or option.

Comment: @chepner apologies; this is with oh-my-zsh.